# I have modified the php file but my WordPress site isn't updating, why?

Tags: wordpress

```
<header class="section-header">
    <h2 class="section-title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Great to have you backkkkkk', 'pustaka' ); ?></h2>
</header>
```

[image: Screenshot of particular component]
[image: Screenshot of edited code]

The correct line was "Great to have you back"... but I edited to see if it works. But after updating the site shows the same thing.

And its same with the original site...

Comment: You're using LiteSpeed Cache (LSC from now on) on that website. Did you make sure to flush LSC's cache after making these changes?

Comment: the change was updated but it took time...